# Multithreading (pthreads)

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm working on a project where I need to make a program run on multiple threads. However, I'm running into a bit of an issue.

In my program, I have an accessory function called 'func_call'.
If I use this in my code:

```
func_call((void*) &my_pixels);
```

The program runs fine.

However, if I try to create a thread, and then run the function on that, the program runs into a segmentation fault.

```
pthread_t thread;
pthread_create (&thread, NULL, (void*)&func_call, (void*) &my_pixels);
```

I've included pthread.h in my program. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: a bit hard to tell from the small fragment given here but is the my_pixels argument going out of scope and then the memory it took up is getting overwritten with some other values leading to random pointer values

Comment: my_pixels is an instance of a struct with the variables that I need to send the function. I initialize the struct and its variables in the main function before calling on the pthread. Once the program enters the func_call function, it saves the variables locally.

Comment: @user: what's the lifetime of `my_pixels`?  How does `func_call` use the thread parameter?  Is there any synchronization between the main thread and `func_call`? Please show the code; an explanation won't provide all relevant details.

Comment: Have you used a debugger, such as gdb, to see where the error is happening?  It may give you an idea what to look for, as you must be referencing some point incorrectly.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that it's a reference error. I just can't figure out where, and why the error doesn't come up when I run the function on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling data in a thread safe manner:

- the thread copies data from the thread argument, which is a pointer to the main thread's `my_pixels` variable; the main thread may exit, making `my_pixles` invalid.
- the thread uses `scene`, main thread calls `free_scene()` on it, which I imagine makes it invalid
- the thread calls `printf()`, the main thread closes `stdout` (kind of unusual itself)
- the thread updates the `picture` array, the main thread accesses `picture` to output data from it

It looks like you should just wait for the thread to finish its work after creating it - call `pthread_join()` to do that.

For a single thread, that would seem to be pointless (you've just turned a multi-threaded program into a single threaded program).  But on the basis of code that's commented out, it looks like you're planning to start up several threads that work on chunks of the data. So, when you get to the point of trying that again, make sure you join *all* the threads you start.  As long as the threads don't modify the same data, it'll work.  Note that you'll need to use separate `my_pixels` instances for each thread (make an array of them, just like you did with `pthreads`), or some threads will likely get parameters that are intended for a different thread.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a bunch! So to join the threads, a simple for loop would suffice, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `func_call` does, it is difficult to give you an answer. Nevertheless, here are few possibilities

1. Does func_call use some sort of a global state - check if that is initialized properly from within the thread. The order of execution of threads is not always the same for every execution
2. Not knowing your operating system (AIX /Linux/Solaris etc) it is difficult to answer this, but please check your compilation options
3. Please provide the `signal` trapped and atleast a few lines of the stack-trace - for all the threads. One thing you can check for yourself is to print the threads' stack-track (using `threads`/`thread` or `pthread` and `thread current <x>` based on the debugger) and and if there is a common data that is being accessed. It is most likely that the segfault occurred when two threads were trying to read off the other's (uncommitted) change

Hope that helps.

Edit:
After checking your code, I think the problem is the global `picture` array. You seem to be modifying that in the thread function without any guards. You loop using `px` and `py` and all the threads will have the same `px` and `py` and will try to write into the `picture` array at the same time. Please try to modify your code to prevent multiple threads from stepping on each other's data modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty sure func_call is initialized correctly. It runs perfectly fine as a standalone function. I'm coding this in C, but running it on a Linux terminal. Also, I'm currently trying to get this code to work on only one thread, before moving on to multiple threads. So, I think the segfault must come up from something else.

Comment: Did the stack-trace of the core file help in narrowing down the possibilities of the cause of the issue. Like @Nick mentioned, it is possible that some pointers in your are data could be corrupt leading to the segfault

Comment: The backtracing isn't helping. I'm convinced it's one of my pointers is to blame, so I'm trying to debug with a few different breakpoints.

Comment: I assume you are talking about modifying the global data by a single thread. And if so, no, it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is `func_call` a function, or a function pointer? If it's a function pointer, there is your problem: you took the address of a function pointer and then cast it.

People are guessing because you've provided only a fraction of the program, which mentions names like `func_call` with no declaration in scope.

Your compiler must be giving you diagnostics about this program, because you're passing a `(void *)` expression to a function pointer parameter.

Define your thread function in a way that is compatible with `pthread_create`, and then just call it without any casts.